# Using LINQ to get Max Count in Junction Table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, junction-table

I have gone through a lot of questions on Stackoverflow and I'm afraid that I still can't find an answer for this. I am using Entity Framework. Using LINQ I am trying to find the most popular class session in the last seven days. I have Four tables involved in the query, Schedules, Sessions, Locations and junction table ClientSesions

The Model for the Schedule is

```
     public class Schedule{
        public Guid ScheduleID { get; set; }
        public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Guid LocationID { get; set; }
        public Guid SessionID { get; set; }
        public Guid SessionTypeID { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentScheduleID { get; set; }
        public int ClassDay { get; set; }
        public int ClassMonth { get; set; }
        public int ClassYear { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ClassDate { get; set; }    
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public int SessionSize { get; set; }    
        public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual SessionType SessionType { get; set; }
 }
```

The Session Model

```
 public class Session {

    public System.Guid SessionID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ProgramID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> SessionTypeID { get; set; }
    public Int32 SessionSize { get; set; }
    public bool Display { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientSession ClientSession { get; set; }
}
```

The Junction ClientSession Table

```
    public class ClientSession
{
    public Guid ClientID { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TransactionID { get; set; }    
    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

I have written the following SQL code which works as expected but I am afraid that I just don't have enough knowledge or experience to convert this to Linq.

```
SELECT TOP 1 s.ClassDate, l.LocationName, COUNT(c.SessionID) as num_att 
FROM Schedules s 
JOIN Sessions ss ON s.SessionID = ss.SessionID
JOIN Sessions ss ON s.SessionID = ss.SessionID
JOIN ClientSessions c ON ss.SessionID = c.SessionID
JOIN Locations l ON s.LocationID = l.LocationID
WHERE s.CompanyID = '109'
AND s.LocationID = '4'
AND (s.ClassDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7,  GETDATE()))
GROUP BY s.ClassDate, l.LocationName
ORDER BY num_att DESC, s.ClassDate DESC
```

This is as far as I managed to get

```
var details = _repositoryBase.AllIncluding<Schedule>(x => x.Session, x => x.Location)
.Where(x => x.CompanyID == mostPopularSessionRequest.CompanyID 
&& x.LocationID == mostPopularSessionRequest.LocationID
.GroupBy(x => x.ClassDate)
```

Any help in showing me how to get the rest of this completed would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help whatsoever.

Comment: Is `_repositoryBase.AllIncluding<Schedule>(x => x.Session, x => x.Location)` already taking care of all the joins in your SQL statement?

Comment: Hey Serv, yeah all the joins are taken care of in the AllIncluding.

Comment: This is a repository code:        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> AllIncluding<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties) where TEntity : class {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = DataContext.Set<TEntity>();
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
            return query;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var query = from s in Schedules
                        join ss in Schedules on s.SessionID equals ss.SessionID
                        join c in ClientSessions on ss.SessionID equals c.SessionID
                        join l in Locations on s.LocationID equals l.LocationID
                        where s.CompanyID =  109  && s.LocationID = 4 && (s.ClassDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                         group c by new
                        {
                            c.ClassDate,
                            l.LocationName 
                        } into gcs
                        select new  
                        {
                            ClassDate = gcs.Key.ClassDate,
                            LocationName = gcs.Key.LocationName,
                            SessionIDCount = gcs.c.Count()
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks P John Raj. I'll give it a shot and see how I go. I'll let you know. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I had to rejig the joins to fit in with my data access but the grouping and select worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I notices one mistake in my side is I join Schedule in two times